# Error while initializing materializecss dropdown from angularjs

Tags: material-design, materialize

I am loading materializecss dropdown dynamically, from an angularjs template. So initializing it at the start when main page is loaded is not working. I added following code to initialize other elements as well as dropdown in the last line

```
//Inside angularjs controller
//Main Left Sidebar Menu
$('.sidebar-collapse').sideNav();

// FULL SCREEN MENU (Layout 02)
$('.menu-sidebar-collapse').sideNav();

// HORIZONTAL MENU (Layout 03)
$('.dropdown-menu').dropdown();

$('.button-collapse').sideNav();

$('.collapsible').collapsible();

$('.dropdown-button').dropdown();
```

Every other elements are getting initialized except the dropdown. I am getting following error due to the last line, if i remove that line everything works fine except dropdowns. I am new to angular js as well as front end development.  I have already searched on web, still not able to find any answer. Appreciate if you help me with this.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
at compositeLinkFn     (http://localhost/TempProject2/js/angular/angular.js:7641:36)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/TempProject2/js/angular/angular.js:7641:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/TempProject2/js/angular/angular.js:7641:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/TempProject2/js/angular/angular.js:7641:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/TempProject2/js/angular/angular.js:7641:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/TempProject2/js/angular/angular.js:7641:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/TempProject2/js/angular/angular.js:7641:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/TempProject2/js/angular/angular.js:7641:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/TempProject2/js/angular/angular.js:7641:13)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/TempProject2/js/angular/angular.js:8241:24) <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Comment: Facing same issue, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by including the dropdown content in the anchor tag that holds the data-activates attribute for the dropdown. Take a look at the code below:

```
  <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
  <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1" id="test">Dropdown<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
  <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
  <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
  </ul>
  </a>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem until I found a hack that worked.

Remove the dropdown-content from the scope of the controller.

```
In SomeController
// add dropdown code
$('.dropdown-button').dropdown();


In your html, place the drop-down content outside the Controller scope
<section ng-controller="SomeController">
  <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1" id="test">Dropdown<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
</section>
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can either place it at the top or bottom. I'm still not sure why this hack works though :)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, wrap the dropdown init with a timeout. Ex:

> $timeout(function(){
>       M.Dropdown.init(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger')); }, 0);

Comment: I don't think this will solve the problem of property not found. It's similar to `var obj;` and then accessing property `a` of obj like `obj.a` which doesn't exist as obj is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

Please initialize `$('.dropdown-button').dropdown();` in `document.ready` function.

It should run after document is ready.